# Write excel file with R keeping time information

Tags: r, excel

I encounter a problem when I try to write an Excel-file (from the xlsx package) from a data frame. The reason I want to write an excel file and not a csv is that I want to keep date format information of certain columns as from a POSIXct formatted column. If there is any other way I am happy with that as well. In the end I need to edit the file in excel anyways.

I have the following data frame

```
##           ID tot_data_leng     wear_leng wear_perc Drop weight age sex
## 1: SWS-A-001   7D 8H 0M 0S  7D 2H 50M 0S      97.1    2     66  66   F
## 2: SWS-A-002            NA            NA        NA    1     NA  NA  NA
## 3: SWS-A-003            NA            NA        NA    2     NA  NA  NA
## 4: SWS-A-004            NA            NA        NA    1     NA  NA  NA
## 5: SWS-A-005            NA            NA        NA    2     NA  NA  NA
## 6: SWS-A-006   7D 0H 0M 0S 5D 20H 49M 0S      83.8    2     54  62   F
##    kcals_per_day cal_days  sed light mod vig tot_MVPA percMVPA dailyMVPA
## 1:         741.4        8 6722  3022 506   0      506      4.9  63.25000
## 2:            NA       NA   NA    NA  NA  NA       NA       NA        NA
## 3:            NA       NA   NA    NA  NA  NA       NA       NA        NA
## 4:            NA       NA   NA    NA  NA  NA       NA       NA        NA
## 5:            NA       NA   NA    NA  NA  NA       NA       NA        NA
## 6:         241.1        7 6507  1694 248   0      248      2.9  35.42857
##                 in_bed              offset tot_bed  waso  arou rest_eff
## 1: 1899-12-30 22:17:30 1899-12-31 07:01:00 523.215 3.785 1.215    98.80
## 2:                <NA>                <NA>      NA    NA    NA       NA
## 3:                <NA>                <NA>      NA    NA    NA       NA
## 4:                <NA>                <NA>      NA    NA    NA       NA
## 5: 1899-12-30 23:43:00 1899-12-31 06:35:00 405.600 9.815 2.450    97.18
## 6: 1899-12-30 22:54:30 1899-12-31 07:00:00 485.500 5.335 2.915    98.48
##    sleep_ti sleep_la avg_awak
## 1:  516.930      2.5    4.345
## 2:       NA       NA       NA
## 3:       NA       NA       NA
## 4:       NA       NA       NA
## 5:  406.515      2.1    4.855
## 6:  478.165      2.0    2.510
```

I then call write.xlsx

```
write.xlsx(ss_acti, file="ss_acti.xlsx", sheetName="Actigrafen", 
    col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE, append=FALSE, showNA=TRUE)
```

This creates the following error message:

```
Error in `[[.factor`(dots[[2L]], 1L) : 
  adding class "factor" to an invalid object
```

Does anyone has a suggestion where the problem is?

Comment: When you write as a csv simply change your date columns into characters and then make the adjustment in excel (format cells > date). I assume your dates were coming in as numbers in seconds since an origin?

Comment: use `str(ss_acti)` to see the classes of each column in the datafframe. If any are factors, then convert them to character with for example `ss_acti$in_bed <- as.character(ss_acti$in_bed)`. Does that fix?

Comment: Hi Amit, thank you. I tried your way first and it worked for me. I would mark it, but as far as I understood stackoverflow I can't vote for comments.